# Trigger single Policy via REST

Tags: azure, cloud, policy, azure-security

is it possible to upload and trigger a single policy for a resource group using the REST API?
Somehow I couldn't find a direct answer to this in the docs.

Something like this in AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_view-compliance.html)

I'd like to only have the result of a single, customly defined, policy that I upload via REST.

Thank you
Best
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $filter to do something like "$filter=policyAssimentID eq '/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{RG-Name}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/{Policyassignment-id}'"

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. 
Is there any further documentation on this? 

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#command-line, however it does not state how to provide any parameter.

Also, do you know if it is possible to provide a management group instead of a resource group? The policies are managed "under" a management group and are not visible to the resource groups.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Here is some information on listing for Management groups: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/policyassignments/listformanagementgroup. I would recommend just look around in that documentation

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

After a lot of trial and error I figured out that it works when not using management groups and therefore simply using the adal tool from github :) 
Now I'm using Adal and a subscription for the first prototype.